# Execute a function for x time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm looking for execute a function on nodejs with express for an exact time, and if the time have pass but the function don't end, the function stop.

I tried with setTimeOut. But it just works for execute a function after "x" time. I just need to execute the function for "x" time.

Answer (score -1):

You could set a Boolean variable and change its value after "x" of time, while checking the same variable in your function.

```js
var Continue = true; // Our Boolean variable.
var x = 5000; // Execute the code for amount of milliseconds.

function canContinue(){
    return Continue;
}

var ourInterval = setInterval( function () {
    if(canContinue())
        console.log("Continue the code for one more second.")  
    else
        clearInterval( ourInterval )
}, 1000 );

setTimeout( function () {
    Continue = false;
}, x);
```

Hope that helps.